# How can I loop through multiple arrays?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 arrays, one filled with questions, the other with answers pertaining to an FAQ page for my current project.

I apologize if this seems like a simple problem, but I'm unsure as to how I'd be able to loop through these arrays, generate the HTML to contain them, and then dynamically insert the questions AND the answers.

The questions on their own are pretty simple, as per the below code

```
@{
   var Questions = ViewData["Questions"];
   var Answers = ViewData["Answers"];
 }
 @foreach (var question in (string[])ViewData["Questions"])
 {
    var html = string.Format(@"
       <div class='panel-group' id='accordion{1}'>
         <div class='panel panel-default'>
           <div class='panel-heading'>
              <h4 class='panel-title'>
                 <a class='accordion-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion{1}' href='#collapse{1}'>{0}</a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div id='collapse{1}' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
             <div class='panel-body'>answer</div>
          </div>
      </div>", question, IDGenerator);
      @Html.Raw(html);
     IDGenerator.Append("1");

   }
```

I have attempted a nested foreach statement to do this, but this generates 6 values and I'm unsure how to insert the values from `Viewdata["Answers"]` into the string, alongside the existing Question without duplication.

Could I perhaps have some insight into this? any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming both arrays contain the same amount of indicies, use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop, see http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_cs_loops.asp

Comment: You should be using a view model representing what you want to display - a collection of `QuestionVM` which contains properties relating to the question and its associated answer(s) so you need a single loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perfect scenario would be create an [`ViewModel`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) with all information you need (question/anwsers) and return a list of viewModels as model to your view. Anyway, give you have the same size for both arrays, you could use an `for` statement and access each element by `index`. For sample:

```
@{
   var questions = (string[]) ViewData["Questions"];
   var answers = (string[]) ViewData["Answers"];
}

@if (questions.Length == answers.Length)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < questions.Lenght; i++)
   {
       // here you can access questions[i] and anwsers[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute saint, thankyou so much it works perfectly =D also I'd just like to point out that  I'm actually abstracting away my DAL to a WCF service, so i'm disinclined to use a ViewModel because this would mean linking my site to the data directly.

Comment: @ReeceCottam, What does that have to do with not doing this properly and using a view model. A view model knows nothing about you DAL

Comment: Yes @ReeceCottam. Adding in what Stephen said, a `ViewModel` could be constructed in your controller with your data and passed to your `View` as a `Model`.

Comment: Ah I see! My apologies gentlemen as I was under the impression a ViewModel had to get its information from a Domain Model, in that case I'll do some research on ViewModels and implement that as appropriate